# Adobe AIR EXE on Windows Store as AppX

Tags: air, windows-store-apps

I'm currently trying to know if I can release a couple of my games on Windows Store. The games are single-file executables and they do not require any additional software installed nor installation. More to say, they performed very well on Steam.

I don't plan to use in-app purchases or ads. The games support any screen resolution and both mouse and touch input and fullscreen mode.

**So is there a way to publish a "not-Visual-Studio" app on Windows Store?**

I have found [this thread](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/4ae1fa49-f0df-4a19-864e-e4bdf19434d6/submitting-adobe-air-apps-to-windows-store?forum=windowsstore) on Windows Dev Center but not sure if the guy succeed with his trial and it seems he was talking about releasing air app, not a standalone .EXE .

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

Adobe Air is not a way you can create a windows store app.  There is a windows desktop bridge for converting .net apps to windows store apps.  There is an ios bridge to convert apps created objective c to windows store apps.  There is also a way to convert web apps to windows store apps.  I am not aware of any way to convert an adobe app air to a windows store app.

Comment: What's about Microsoft's App converter called Project Centennial? https://www.facebook.com/groups/stage3d/permalink/1122551767809197/  https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/Build/2015/2-692